# Not understanding this behaviour of PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace

[image]Here is an array I am preparing for my task

```
<?php 
    $findArray = array();
    $findArray[] = '{{var1}}';
    $findArray[] = '{{var2}}';
    $findArray[] = '{{var3}}';
    $findArray[] = '{{var4}}';
?>
```

Now the problem is when I `print_r` this array I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
)
```

Here is the `var_dump` output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) ""
  [1]=>
  string(8) ""
  [2]=>
  string(8) ""
  [3]=>
  string(8) ""
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong and why?

> As @postrel suggested to check for template engine, and as I am using
>   Twig this behavior comes in the picture when I am trying to print the
>   array after the twig environment setup, when I did the same before
>   setup of twig environment, it worked as expected.

Comment: I get it right. Are you adding any angular js library to your file? Is this the only content in your page?

Comment: what is var1, var2 etc. A variable in php starts with $ sign.

Comment: No not using Angular @Thamilan

Comment: No they are custom token strings not variables which are going to be replaced @AmitRay

Comment: check your code again, It's working https://3v4l.org/LMmKD

Comment: What is your file encoding ?

Comment: `string(8) ""` but do not display. It must be something. Your code encoding, Browser encoding, Browser plugin (try to view source). I have no other idea

Comment: May be I should dig for encoding as per your suggestion, thanks alot @NgôVănThao

Comment: @GHOST93 do you have a template engine?

Comment: @postrel Yes! and twig has this kind of syntax, and it worked when I removed the array from twig environment, thanks a lot man!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values as an array this way

```
$findArray = array();
$findArray[] = '{{var1}}';
$findArray[] = '{{var2}}';
$findArray[] = '{{var3}}';
$findArray[] = '{{var4}}';

$newarray = array();
foreach ($findArray as $arr){
    if (preg_match("~\{\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}~", $arr, $atr))
        $newarray[] = $atr[1];

}

var_dump($newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your values are being substituted to values by some templating engine when you dump them. Try writing them into a file, check the file contents, the curly bracket notation will be there. If you want it on screen (in browser), you'll have to escape or html-encode the curlies.